# Why are the css images or js not loading in my laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, image

This is a follow up question of lasat one I gott ittt to  worrking the  site is opening and all & at first it was loading the css, js & images too but now it has stopped  loading the files and in the console I'm getting these  errors =>

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:35

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/fontawesome.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:37

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/magnific-popup.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:39

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/slick.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:41

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:225

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/hero/hero_shape_1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:833

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.6.0.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:835

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/slick.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:837

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:839

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:841

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:843

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:845

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:846

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:849

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:857

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/panel/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:859

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/panel/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:861

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/panel/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

typed.js:617 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tagName')
at t.value (typed.js:617:31)
at new t (typed.js:92:33)
at (index):867:5
value @ typed.js:617
t @ typed.js:92
(anonymous) @ (index):867
(index):898 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at (index):898:5
(anonymous) @ (index):898
127.0.0.1/:281

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/bg/feature-card_bg1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:284

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/feature-icon1-1.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:298

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/feature-icon1-2.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:312

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/feature-icon1-3.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:333

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/normal/about_1-1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:334

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/normal/about_1-2.png 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:353

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/about-icon.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:383

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/bg/sec-shape-top.png 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:398

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/normal/wcu_1-2.png 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:400

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/normal/wcu_1-1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:404

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/wcu-icon_1-1.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:476

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/bg/sec-shape-bottom.png 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:495

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/service-icon_2-1.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:507

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/service-icon_2-2.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:74

```
   GET http://localhostpublic/logo-b1.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

127.0.0.1/:104

```
   GET http://localhostpublic/logo-b.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

127.0.0.1/:715

```
   GET http://localhostpublic/logo-w.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

127.0.0.1/:519

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/service-icon_2-3.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:581

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/counter-icon_1-1.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:592

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/counter-icon_1-2.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:603

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/counter-icon_1-3.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:614

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icon/counter-icon_1-4.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

manifest.json:1

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
```

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

I tried changing the file path style but it did not work as expected nothing is being loaded what could bee the reason for it?

Comment: First question: Do you have a path `public/assets` in your project root?

Comment: @Paladin Yes I do have that path.

Comment: I assume you are using the `artisan serve` command, is that right? In case it's right, please check one of the 404 links to be a valid target on your maschine.
Example: If `http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json` is the 404 request, please check if the file `public/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json` is on your harddisk.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `APP_URL` in your .env file to http://127.0.0.1:8000, should do the trick.